# Read confirmation with PHPMAILER

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I try to return a reading confirmation when send an email with PHPMAILER but it doesn't works :(

I tried these options :

*Construction of the object:*

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->From = 'prenom.nom@mail.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Nom Prénom';
$mail->addAddress($Desti);
$mail->addCC($CC);
$mail->addBCC($BCC);
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = 'MON SUJET';
$mail->Body = $MonTexteMail;
```

**first solution** :

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader( 'X-pmrqc: 1' );
$mail->AddCustomHeader( "X-Confirm-Reading-To: mail.confirm@domain.com" );
```

**Second solution**

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader( "Return-receipt-to: mail.confirm@domain.com" );
```

**third solution**

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader( "Disposition-Notification-To:<mail.confirm@domain.com>");
```

**Fourth solution**

```
$mail->ConfirmReadingTo = "mail.confirm@domain.com";
```

But nothing works,

Comment: You are aware that this only works if the receiver _lets_ their mail client send such a confirmation, right?

Comment: Yes I know, it's in a company, everyone is on outlook and is configured to send automatically the reading receipt if there is one.

Comment: Well then do two things: 1. Check what the actual header looks like that Outlook produces for requesting a confirmation, and 2. check if that header makes it correctly into the sent email when you are trying to replicate it for the email that your script sends.

Comment: When I send a message with a read receipt from Outlook, on the header I do not have a special line for the accused to read .. but I get it...

if i used this in the header with PHPMAILER 
`X-Confirm-Reading-To: <mail@domain.com>`
I see this line in the header... but it doesn't works ! 

and if i used this header in PHPMAILER
`Disposition-Notification-To: <mail@domain.com>`
nothing in the header and no read receipt :/

Answer (score 8):

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader( "X-Confirm-Reading-To: your@email.com" );

$mail->AddCustomHeader( "Return-receipt-to: your@email.com" );
```

This works, Outlook/Gmail/Thunderbird detects it and requests confirm, I used it today for a little script.

Answer (score 4):

I found that capitalization is important to some email client programs. Also some use Disposition-Notification-To. This is what I reccommend:

```
$mail->AddCustomHeader( "X-Confirm-Reading-To: $eUser" );
$mail->AddCustomHeader( "Return-Receipt-To: $eUser" );
$mail->AddCustomHeader( "Disposition-Notification-To: $eUser" );
```

Answer (score 0):

The read receipt email will send to the email address you provide:

```
$mail->ConfirmReadingTo = "email@address.com";
```